# How can I pass Ctrl+Tab to the parent window in C#?

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, parent, sendkeys

My WinForm dialog is attached to a 3rd party window (SolidWorks) via a call to `SetParent` (p/invoke). My dialog is in the 3rd parties process as an add-in.

When my user has given my dialog/widget focus by clicking on it, if they then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch views in the parent application, my dialog receives the key stroke sequence - I can see this by overriding `ProcessCmdKey`. The command is not passed to the parent window, and hence does nothing.

**How can I pass this key sequence to the parent HWND?**

It's not just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> I need to forward, it's all key's including <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, etc. etc.

Comment: You'd be far better off removing the `C#` tag and replacing it with `windows` and `winapi` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindWindow` to get the handle of your parent window. (Pass null for lpClassName) (More info: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.FindWindow)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

Forward the captured messages using `SendMessageW` (more info: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage)

```
// Works for unicode. One can also 
// use CharSet = CharSet.Unicode instead of [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageW")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, 
                                  UInt32 Msg, 
                                  IntPtr wParam, 
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);
```

Comment: I have the window handle stored from my call to SetParent, however the forwarding of the message is not having the desired affect. I've also tried using the main window handle for the process.  <br/>


  protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
  {
   Debug.WriteLine(keyData.ToString());
   //NativeMethods.SendMessage(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, (uint)msg.Msg, msg.WParam, msg.LParam);
   NativeMethods.SendMessage(mParentWin.Handle, (uint)msg.Msg, msg.WParam, msg.LParam);
   return false;
  }

Any ideas?

Comment: @user1079741 Capture the relevant messages in `WndProc`, I assume there will be more.